# Measuring the power consumed by raspberry pi 3

Tags: pi-3b+

I have powered up my RPi and I want to know which signal could be used to measure the current consumed by the RPi. I have DAQ card and I would like to know which part (or signal) I can use to measure the current? since the power is connected directly through Micro USB from the supply. Is there any option to measure the current being consumed by the RPi?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I measure the current power consumption?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/2136/how-do-i-measure-the-current-power-consumption)

Comment: @Milliways They have discussed about using which device to measure the current, but i need to know which signal (wire of the signal) I could use to measure the current

Comment: There is no current measuring point. You need to do this external to the Pi. Measuring current in a low voltage circuit is a non trivial task ang normally requires an isolated tool.

Comment: I have the tool to measure current, I don't know from where in RPi should I take the wire to measure current with an external tool.

Comment: you measure the current flowing into the RPi through the power supply cable

Comment: Is there any point in doing this? Are you trying to run on a battery? If so you have to measure between the battery and the RPi. Voltage is easy, you measure across the load. Amps need a break in the circuit as you measure in series with the load.

Comment: Also see https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=254247

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it with a software from inside you OS. You have to do this with a multimeter externally.