# How to read AC current sensor (10,12 channel's)

Tags: arduino

I have a python program which needs to read the power, voltage and current. (Raspberry , I2C & CT Sensor)

Please explain whether Arduino is required if we are using Raspberry. Is it possible to bypass Arduino and use Raspberry to install library to fulfil ADC feature and further calculations.

**I wanted to know what is the requirement of Arduino, Is it possible to calculate power energy without arduino?**

As we are new to this, please advise.

Comment: Arduino is not needed, but the RPi will require additional hardware. [This answer provides some alternatives.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/118465/83790)

Comment: Please can you share which hardware required or suitable list

Comment: This might also help: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/94403/rpi-current-sensing-using-acs712-and-ina219. Cheers.