# Which is better to measure voltage and current,INA219 or current/voltage sensors?

Tags: raspbian, voltage, current

I wanted to know if the measurement could be better, more accurate using INA219 or voltage/current sensors connected with ADCs? Also considering the time to implement both systems, which would give me more advantages?

Comment: please define `better`

Comment: Sorry,what should I define better?

Comment: define what you mean by the word "better" ... it means different things to different people

Comment: Try posting the technical details such as volts and amps. These values have a big impact on sensor choice. You could be controlling .01uA or maybe 1000A  more or less, we do not know. What accuracy do you need. How many digits do you want to display, response time,  etc.

Comment: I understand,but my battery isnt finished.I think that would be a normal battery and the values also same,mabye smaller.

Answer (score 2):

Use the 1NA219, or any other IC that offers 'high-side' measurement.

To explain: current is measured by putting a small resistor in the battery line; say you have a 12V battery and it is feeding 1 amp, then if you use a 0.1 ohm resistor, one side of the resistor will be 12V, the other 11.9V. To measure these voltages with an ADC you have to use potential dividers on both voltages, maybe 5:1 so the voltages become 2.4 and 2.38 volts.

Note that you have reduced the difference between the two voltages, so will have lost a lot of accuracy in your measurement; also you've connected a potential divider across your battery which will waste some of its power.

High-side measurement gets round this problem by giving you the difference between the two resistor voltages, so is a lot easier to work with.

Comment: I don't follow your explanation of the high side measurement advantage, and wondered if you could cite a reference to support that? A technical article or app note - something like that...

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to the [other question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/135059/how-to-measure-voltage-and-current-of-a-battery-with-raspberry-pi) you asked. I'm not sure if you read the [answer that I suggested](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/118465/83790) in a comment to that question, but I do feel it also answers this question. By that, I mean if you define "better" as high accuracy and ease of integration, the INA260 is an excellent choice.

And FWIW: The primary difference between the INA219 and the INA260 is that the INA260 has the current-sensing resistor built into the chip. Unless you have some fairly unusual or extreme requirements, that makes the INA260 the clear choice for "better".