# Get Measurements from Battery/Solar Setup

Tags: gpio, battery, power-management, hat, measuring

I'm planning a setup with an rpi3b+ and the [pijuice hat (battery) and pijuice solar module](https://uk.pi-supply.com/products/pijuice-solar). It is key to my project that I can access the following data digitally i.e. in the pi:

- current power consumption of the pi
- current power output from the solar panel
- battery charge in %

The pijuice hat connects directly to the pi's 40-pin gpio header and is already supplying me with the battery charge in percent. The panel is plugged into the power management board (hat).

What components do I need to measure the consumption of the pi and the output from the panel?

Comment: This is not Pi specific.  You could choose any peripheral with any battery with any computer and come up with the same answer.

Comment: [This might help](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/118465/83790)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was in their documentation all along, I was simply looking for the wrong thing. Both input and output can the read via their [api](https://github.com/PiSupply/PiJuice/blob/master/Software/README.md#status).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is a coulomb counter. Looking at the pijuice Hat you linked to I do not see that function. Take a look at Grove coulomb counter, it is based on the LTC2941 by analog devices. It is also sold in the Arduino arena. There are several available from different sources and/or you can make your own.

Comment: According to the OP, "The pijuice hat connects directly to the pi's 40-pin gpio header and is ***already supplying me with the battery charge in percent.***" IOW, sounds like he's got the Coulomb counter & wants to "measure the consumption of the pi and the output from the panel"   Whaddya' think?